# How to get class names of table tds and write it to an array using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML table with three rows and three cells for each row. Each cell has class name. I want to get the class name of each cell and write it to array.

HTML table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="O-marker"></td>
        <td class="O-marker"></td>
        <td class="X-marker"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="X-marker"></td>
        <td class="O-marker"></td>
        <td class="X-marker"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="X-marker"></td>
        <td class="O-marker"></td>
        <td class="O-marker"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When the `getBoard` function is called, then get all the class names of cells and write it to `board` array.

```
function getBoard() {
   var board = [];
   return board;
}
```

I want to use jQuery and `.each()` method to get the class name and push the first character into the array `board`. Example. By the first character I mean (X or O).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using vanilla JS:

```js
function getBoard() {
  var board = [];
  var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i += 1) {
    board.push(tds[i].className[0]);
  }
  return board;
}
```

Or in jQuery:

```js
function getBoard() {
  var board = [];
  $('td').each(function(){
    board.push(this.className[0]);
  });
  return board;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
function getBoard() {
   var board = [];

   $('.table td').each(function (index) {
       board.push($(this).attr('class')[0]);
   });

   return board;
}

console.log(getBoard());
```

You can treat the string as an array (sort of?) and get the first character with `[0]`.